# antlr reverse phrase match issue

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have a rule like this,

```
BLOCK_COMMENT
    : ('/*' ~[!] .*? '*/' | '/**/') -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

But when I try to match this line,

```
/**/and /**/1=1
```

The `and` symbol is HIDDEN as well. Since ANTLR is greedy, it matched the last occurrence of `*/`, and it end up with only one BLOCK_COMMENT (I was expecting two)

So, I will need something that matches `not '*/'`, and the BLOCK_COMMENT rule should become:

`'/*'` then not `'*/'` then `'*/'`

Anyone know what rules can match `not '*/'`?

Comment: Do you explicitly need something that can match `not '*/'`? Or do you just need the solution for the comments?

Comment: @cantSleepNow Both, I thought it might be `~('*/')`

Comment: I think that `~` can only operate on single char. Or set of single chars. In any way if you don't need to parse the comments (just detect them) something like this should do `COMMENT : '/*' .*? '*/' -> channel(HIDDEN);`

Comment: @cantSleepNow I need to interpret the comments ... e.g `/*! xxx */`

Comment: In that case you should use lexical modes.

Answer (score 0):

First here is a quote from the book 'Definitive ANTLR4 Reference' on the `~` operator on lexer rules:

> ~x   Match any single character not in the set described by x . Set x
>   can be a single character literal, a range, or a subrule set like
>   ~('x'|'y'|'z') or ~[xyz] .

so basically we can't use something like `~'*/'`.

Since you need to interpret the comments themselfs as well, best way to do it IMHO is with lexer modes.

```
...
COMMENT_START : '/*' -> mode (COMMENT_MODE);
mode COMMENT_MODE;
COMMENT_END : '*/' -> mode (DEFAULT_MODE);
//match anything else that you need in this mode
...
```

I have assumed that you only have one mode in addition to the default one. Of course if you have more of them, you can also use `popMode` and `pushMode`.